# Как написать почтовый клиент на чистом PHP

Tags: php, sql, email, pop3, phpmailer

Мне нужно написать почтовый клиент на PHP. В нем должны присутствовать две вкладки, "Входящие" и "Отправленные". Как реализовать функционал "Отправленные" я понимаю, через функцию `mail()`.

Правильно я понял, что нужно будет сохранять копии писем в БД, а потом их выводить?

Но как реализовать функционал "Входящие"? Мне не совсем понятно. Нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: На затравку http://php-zametki.ru/php-nachinayushhim/72-pop3-protokol-s-primerami.html

Comment: pop3 который вам предлагают выше для таких целей плохо пригоден ибо заставит сохранять копии всех писем в БД и выводить статус от туда же. Лучше использовать протокол IMAP, если его поддерживает почтовый сервер. Он позволяет хранить все прямо на почтовом сервере, искать по разным критериям и т.п.  и вы в php скрипте можете спокойно вообще нигде у себя ничего не хранить получая всегда прямо с imap-сервера

Comment: @Mike pop3 не всегда обязывает удалять письма с сервера :)

Comment: @Mike Можно с Вами связаться как-то? Оч нужна помощь.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Удалять не обязывает. Но кроме удаления есть такие вещи как статус "просмотрено"

Comment: @Mike, который к слову так же доступен :)

Comment: @АлександрСалычев А смысл со мной связываться, я не представляю как из php работать с почтовыми протоколами. наверняка есть какие то библиотеки. и наверняка все о них можно найти на php.net просто по названию протокола. И еще можете  посмотреть RoundeCube он целиком написан на php и является полноценным почтовым клиентом

Comment: Но вцелом согласен, imap предпочтительней. Хотя с pop3 меньше граблей.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем "связываться" с кем-то. Если задача учебная, то ее и делать надо самому. А если нужно не написать, а нужен клиент, то их готовых, как собак не резаных.

Answer (score 3):

Почтовый сервер свой, или сторониий от яндекса/гугла? Учитывая, что на PHP, клиент будет так же на сервере, который постоянно в сети?

Не храните почту в базе, пусть лежит на сервере.

Не отправляйте почту функцией mail(), вам предварительно придется сформировать письмо согласно всем RFC, это совсем не просто, так что хватит писать велосипеды, используйте библиотеки PHPmailer или SwiftMailer.
 Второй по описаниям мне приглянулся больше, но у него странный валидатор, не пропускает исходящие на почту в четырехбуквенной доменной зоне (.info .club .name и тп), или просто я не смог его заставить сделать это.

Используйте функции [IMAP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imap.php) для работы с письмами в папках (просмотр-удаление и тд)